# Filtering a panel dataset in r

Tags: r

I have a dataframe of this form

```
familyid memberid occupation panelid year
1        1        1          1       2000
1        2        1          1       2000
2        1        1          1       2000 
2        2        2          1       2000
3        1        1          1       2000
3        2        1          1       2000
3        3        1          1       2000
1        1        2          2       2001
1        2        1          2       2001
2        1        2          2       2001
2        2        2          2       2001
3        1        1          2       2001
3        2        2          2       2001
3        3        2          2       2001
```

I want to filter this dataframe in order to get the following.

```
familyid memberid occupation panelid year
1        1        1          1       2000
2        1        1          1       2000 
3        2        1          1       2000
3        3        1          1       2000
1        1        2          2       2001
2        1        2          2       2001
3        2        2          2       2001
3        3        2          2       2001
```

In words, I want to keep only the panel obs that present occupation==1 in year 2000 (panelid==1) and occupation==2 in year 2001 (panelid==2). Does anybody know how to do this? Many thank to everyone,

Marco

Comment: Try `subset(df1, (occupation == 1 & year == 2000) | (occupation == 2 & year == 2001))`

Comment: Note that in the input there are 6 observations where occuopation is 1 and year is 2000.  So, not clear how some rows got removed in the expected

Comment: Not sure if the `panelid` being the same as the `occpuation` is coincidence or not, or if you prefer `year` to `panelid`, but you could also do `subset(df1, panelid == occpuation)`

Comment: @akrun it is because I want to keep only family members that shift from occupation 1 in year 2000 to occupation 2 in year 2001. If a family member has occupation 1 in both years 2000 and 2001, I want it to be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, we can group by 'familyid', 'memberid', `filter` based on `any` 'occupation' 1 and 'year' 2000 as well as `any` 'occupation' 2 and 'year' 2001

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(familyid, memberid) %>% 
  filter(any(occupation == 1 & year == 2000) & any(occupation == 2 & year == 2001))
# A tibble: 8 x 5
# Groups:   familyid, memberid [4]
#  familyid memberid occupation panelid  year
#     <int>    <int>      <int>   <int> <int>
#1        1        1          1       1  2000
#2        2        1          1       1  2000
#3        3        2          1       1  2000
#4        3        3          1       1  2000
#5        1        1          2       2  2001
#6        2        1          2       2  2001
#7        3        2          2       2  2001
#8        3        3          2       2  2001
```

---

Or if the levels of 'occupation' and 'year' are only two, then we can also count with `n_distinct` to create a logical vector for `filter`ing

```
df1 %>% 
  group_by(familyid, memberid) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(occupation) >1 & n_distinct(year)> 1)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(familyid = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), memberid = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L), occupation = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), panelid = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), year = c(2000L, 
2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 
2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-14L))
```

Comment: Thank you so much akrun!